# UnityをAndroidでデバックした際にでるエラーの解消法

Tags: unity3d

UnityでAndroidアプリをビルドした際に

```
Building Player was cancelled
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Unable to find unity activity in manifest. You need to make sure orientation             attribute is set to portrait manually.
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

と出てアプリが起動できません。
対処法教えてください。

ちなみにとある広告SDKを導入する際にこのエラーが発生しました。

環境はUnity4.6です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

とある広告SDKとのことですが、そのSDKはUnity4.6に対応しているものでしょうか？
また、Unity4.6以前では問題がなかったということでしょうか？

Unity4.6ではuGUI搭載などで大幅に手が入っているのでOnGUIでのエラーとなるとUIまわりでの問題ではないかと思うのですが、どの広告SDKなのかがわかれば、もう少し的確な回答が寄せられるのではないかと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
SDKの仕様書確認したら対応バージョンはUnity4.5となっていました。
Unity4.6での仕様の変更があったのでそこに対応出来てい無いのでは無いかと思いました。

SDKはadcropsとApplipromotionです。